# OpenCV error when trying to use opencv_createsamples

Tags: python, opencv, annotations, haar-classifier

I'm trying to train a cascade to detect faces. I have 31 pictures with faces in them and I've used `opencv_annotation` tool to generate the `-info` -file. The file looks like this:

```
1 positiveImages/0.jpg 1 546 289 70 96
2 positiveImages/1.jpg 1 542 325 105 106
3 positiveImages/10.jpg 1 98 289 138 119
4 positiveImages/11.jpg 1 284 303 204 189
5 positiveImages/12.jpg 3 415 279 70 97 484 320 75 87 624 374 76 132
...
```

After this I've tried to use the `opencv_createsamples` tool to produce the `.vec` -file to be used to train the cascade. This is the command I've used:

```
opencv_createsamples -info file.txt -bg negatives.txt -vec cropped.vec -num 1920 -w 48 -h 48
```

This gives me the following output with an error:

```
Info file name: file.txt
Img file name: (NULL)
Vec file name: cropped.vec
BG  file name: negatives.txt
Num: 1920
BG color: 0
BG threshold: 80
Invert: FALSE
Max intensity deviation: 40
Max x angle: 1.1
Max y angle: 1.1
Max z angle: 0.5
Show samples: FALSE
Width: 48
Height: 48
Create training samples from images collection...
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ssize.area() > 0) in resize, file /home/travis/miniconda/conda-bld/conda_1486587069159/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 3229
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/travis/miniconda/conda-bld/conda_1486587069159/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:3229: error: (-215) ssize.area() > 0 in function resize

Aborted (core dumped)
```

As far as I can understand, this error wants to tell me that there is no image, am I right? I wonder why this happens. The `file.txt` seems to be ok, it has the right paths for images etc. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Edit. Wondering if there is some better way to train a cascade for example with a few thousand pictures of faces and a few thousand pictures without faces and not using the annotation tool? Could I somehow just use the two folders for training if the positive images are cropped so that they contain only faces?

Edit. My folder structure is like this:

```
/negativeImages
/positiveImages
file.txt
negatives.txt
```

I'm running `opencv_createsamples` from the root.

Comment: can you show your folder hierarchy and from where you are running the createsamples? Probably a problem with relative pathes. If you are very very sure that pathes are ok, try to reduce the file systematically to find errneous annotations or broken/missing files.

Comment: @Micka I edited my original post.

Comment: with root directory you mean the linux root directory? Can you try /positiveImages/0.jpg in your info file? About your new question: If positive images are cropped then your annotation 5 doesnt make sense (there seem to be 3 faces in one image). I rypically used cropped images as well, but you'll still need the info file. But with cropped images you can easily write a script to generate the info file!

Comment: I mean from the project root, from where are folders `negativeImages` and `positiveImages` and files `file.txt` and `negatives.txt`.

Comment: Btw. @Micka Do you happen to know what dataset was used to train `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`? Can't seem to find that information anywhere.

Comment: probably INRIA dataset was used. Have a look at the original Viola & Jones paper. Maybe you can find the contributor of the xml file from the git commit.

Comment: I get the same error but when the num count is < 951 error does not come, but i have 3200 samples to train. any idea how to fix the same.